# Redis: Proper caching of responses from API in httparty client, expire cache respecting the cache headers in api response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis, httparty

In my new rails app, which is an API consumer/client. I'm using httParty to request. I am using code suggested in this post http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/ruby-tutorial-building-a-robust-json-api-client/140

```
def handle_caching(options)
    if cached = $redis.get(cache_key(options))
      eval(cached)
    else
      yield.tap do |results|
        $redis.set(cache_key(options), results)
      end
    end
  end
```

But it caches pages permanently and pages are not being expired when there is change in content in api. How do I properly expire cache respecting the cache headers in the API response.

Answer (score 0):

Expiry in redis can be obtained by setting a TTL on the key I.e. a certain time to live. This will only work in case you know beforehand as to what is the optimal TTL for your keys. Redis will expire the key after the specified TTL.

However, you will have to manually invalidate / update the cache whenever there are changes in the cache headers in the API response.